# Convert number to date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, time

I get a number representing date from a back-end, and I'm trying to convert it to a date this way:

```
number = item["created"].to_i
number #=> 1512387277084
DateTime.strptime(number.to_s ,'%s') #=> 49895-08-24T08:58:04+00:00
Time.at(number).utc #=> 49895-08-24 08:58:04 UTC
Time.at(number) #=> 49895-08-24 11:58:04 +0300
```

But this is a wrong result.

If I use Epoch & Unix Timestamp Conversion Tools, I get this result:

```
1512387277084
Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:
GMT: Monday, December 4, 2017 11:34:37.084 AM
Your time zone: Monday, December 4, 2017 2:34:37.084 PM GMT+03:00
```

`Time.at(number)` doesn't work.

How to convert it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime.strptime('1512387277084', '%Q')
#⇒ #<DateTime: 2017-12-04T11:34:37+00:00
#       ((2458092j,41677s,84000000n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

[`DateTime` formatting](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime).

Answer (score 1):

According to [the ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-c-at) takes the `at` method, of the `Time` class, as argument "the number of seconds" since the Epoch not the "milliseconds" since the Epoch.
Another variant takes as arguments the "seconds" since the Epoch and "Microseconds with frac".

You need to convert `number` (the input) from `ms` to `sec` and `us` to get the expected / correct result.

**Examples**

Wrong (ms interpeted as seconds):

```
> number = 1512387277084 # ms since epoch
=> 1512387277084
> Time.at(number)
=> 49895-08-24 10:58:04 +0200
```

Seconds with fractal:

```
> number2 = number / 1000.0
=> 1512387277.084
> Time.at(number2)
=> 2017-12-04 12:34:37 +0100
> Time.at(number2).usec
=> 84000
> Time.at(number2).nsec
=> 84000110 # Wrong of by 110 ns 

> Time.at(number2.round(3)).nsec
=> 84000110 # Wrong of by 110 ns
> Time.at(number2.round(2)).usec
=> 79999 # Wrong
> Time.at(number2.round(2)).nsec
=> 79999923 # Wrong
```

Seconds only:

```
> number3 = number / 1000
=> 1512387277
> Time.at(number3)
=> 2017-12-04 12:34:37 +0100
> Time.at(number3).usec
=> 0 # Wrong
> Time.at(number3).nsec
=> 0 # Wrong
```

Seconds and Microseconds:

```
ms = number % 1000 # Milliseconds
=> 84
> us = ms * 1000 # Microseconds
=> 84000
> Time.at(number3, us)
=> 2017-12-04 12:34:37 +0100
> Time.at(number3, us).usec
=> 84000 # OK
> Time.at(number3, us).nsec
=> 84000000 # OK
> Time.at(number3, us).to_f
=> 1512387277.084 # OK
```

**Update 2**

Seconds as Rational

```
> number4 = number.quo(1000)
=> (378096819271/250)
> Time.at(number4)
=> 2017-12-04 12:34:37 +0100
> Time.at(number4).usec
=> 84000 # OK
> Time.at(number4).nsec
=> 84000000 # OK
> Time.at(number4).to_f
=> 1512387277.084 # OK
```

Comment: You do have to divide `number` by 1000 in order to use `Time.at`, but using floating point division will **not** give the correct result: `Time.at(number2).nsec` returns `84000110`. The correct result would be `84000000` – yours is 110 nanoseconds off.

Comment: @Stefan updated my answer to take your input into account. Thx.

Comment: Doesn't have to be that complicated: `Time.at(number.quo(1000))`